# Unpredictable hierarchy in JSON object

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, json, dom

When building an ajax application, I normally prefer fetching remote data in JSON format. However, when the hierarchy is unpredictable ([specifically geocoding responses from Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=606)), it is tempting to go with XML format because the DOM method getElementsByTagName will get the data wherever it is in the hierarchy. Assuming there is only one element/property with the tag/name I'm interested in, is the following function an efficient equivalent to getElementsByTagName? How can it be improved?

```
function findProperty(obj,prop){

        for(var p in obj){
            if(p==prop){
                    return obj[p];
            }
            if(obj[p] instanceof Object){
                var tmp = findProperty(obj[p],prop);
                if(tmp){
                    return tmp;
                }
            }

        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function seems like a pretty straight forward linear search which many DOM traversal functions will do. That said, you should add a hasOwnProperty check to avoid getting properties from the prototype tree. e.g.

```
for(var p in obj) {
   if(obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      ...
   }
}
```

Also, **always** use === instead of == in JS (this avoids, the rather bad, type coercion in JS). I'm also not sure that the instanceof statement does what you think it does. You'd probably want to use:

```
obj[o].constructor === Object
```

instead.

Comment: `instanceof` should be identical to `constructor` check here, although both will fail to "match" objects from other frames. 

It's also good to remember that `hasOwnProperty` is missing in some of the older clients, such as Safari <2.0.4.

Comment: instanceof *should* be the same, but as an example under FF 3.5 the following will return false:
"as" instanceof String
while this will return true:
"as".constructor === String